# Firefox OS cross origin framing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cors, firefox-os

I am getting

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://example.com does not permit framing.

error for HTTPS secure. But the normal HTTP works fine in `<iframe>`.

Which settings are required in Mozilla Firefox `manifest.webapp` for this?

Or other solution for this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [mozbrowser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Using_the_Browser_API) API to load the iframe. Frames loaded through mozbrowser are not subject to the X-Frame-Options policy.

Comment: Yes I have use that only. It turns the <iframe> to browser level. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When your browser is requesting the page you are trying to display in the frame, it is being told by the server hosting it that it is not allowed to display it in a frame.

You need to reconfigure that server so that permission is not forbidden.

Comment: I need to open the Secure payment Gateway page in iframe. Is their other way to do so without using <iframe> tag?

Comment: No. Discuss the problem with your payment gateway provider. Find out what their actual policy for framing is.